# React onSubmit wait for async IIFE inside the function to update state with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

Is there a way to wait for this state(customerId => setCustomerId) to update?

When user signs up, he/she is redirected and the form unmounts.

I tried using IIFE so it runs immediately upon submit but no luck, useEffect also wont work because I cant wrap the onSubmit function in useEffect scope, at least I think it wont work.

Can someone enlighten me about this, it is crucial to update the user document in firebase upon sign up(that is what UserDataProvider() does) to prevent future complications.

```
const onSubmit = (formData: FormData) => {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
    (async function () {
      const customer = await axios.post('/api/create_customer', {
        email: 'testemail@test.com',
        name: `Dario Kolic`,
      });
      setCustomerId(customer.data);
    })();
    console.log(customerId);
    return auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(formData.email, formData.password)
      .then(() => {
        return new UserDataProvider().set({
          customerId: customerId,
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        // window.location.href = '/terms_of_service';
      });
  };
```

Comment: So you want the `axios.post` to happen before `auth.createUser...`? If that is so it should suffice to make `onSubmit` an async function and then using `await axios.post...` directly in `onSubmit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

First IIFE only have async call that why second return executed immediately without waiting for customerid update. That means second function executed before customerid update

Better use default `then callback` function instead of await. why you are using return statement inside the `onsubmit` event. i think that should be no effect.

```js
const onSubmit = (formData: FormData) => {
  document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
  axios.post('/api/create_customer', {
    email: 'testemail@test.com',
    name: `Dario Kolic`,
  }).then((customer) => {
    setCustomerId(customer.data);
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(formData.email, formData.password)
      .then(() => {
        return new UserDataProvider().set({
          customerId: customer.data,
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
        // window.location.href = '/terms_of_service';
      });
  })
};
```